# Replacing <legend> with <div> in Zend_Form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have a problem with aligning my legends in forms, and reading the decorator documentation did not exactly make it much clear for me how i can replace the  tag with a normal .

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring only to the legend tag in the field set, or to the elements labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## **EDIT**

I'm very sorry, I was still thinking about **label**, not **legend**. To replace legend tag (which is generated when you're using subforms or manually add `fieldset` decorator to your form and call `$form->setLegend('some')`) with another one, you have two options.

1. Write your own `fieldset` view helper (`Zend_View_Helper_Fieldset`), and put it into your application helpers directory. It will force ZF to take your helper instead this one located in library folder. In that original helper you have:

   ```
   // get legend
   $legend = '';
   if (isset($attribs['legend'])) {
       $legendString = trim($attribs['legend']);
       if (!empty($legendString)) {
           $legend = '<legend>'
                   . (($escape) ? $this->view->escape($legendString) : $legendString)
                   . '</legend>' . PHP_EOL;
       }
       unset($attribs['legend']);
   }
   ```

   You can replace legend tag with div in your helper and it will work.
2. Second way to achieve that, is just add HtmlTag decorator to your Zend_Form element instance. Look here, it's great tutorial how to use decorators in ZF: http://devzone.zend.com/1240/decorators-with-zend_form/

Sorry for misleading you at the beginning :(

Comment: thanks for your reply, i honestly tried to read the decorator doc and i still dont quite understand how i am meant to use it in my situation. I have no problem styling, but styling legends is apperantly not the best thing, as it will screw up in browser such as IE/Firefox.. I would rather convert them to <div>'s.

Comment: Styling labels it's very basic stuff, which even IE can handle. Depends of usage of `display`. Remember, that label also have semantic meaning.

Comment: the labels are not a problem, although the legends are. Im using negative positioning which firefox does not support for some reason, there has been posted an error on that which seems to be a CSS bug, so until then im forced to replace the tag with something as a DIV to avoid it.

Comment: @JavaCake so solution for you is not to use label decorator, just html element decorator. Or write your own label decorator.

Comment: can you give me an example on how to create this decorator? I like the idea of the legend on the group, but it shouldnt be a <legend>..

Comment: big ups! Thanks alot for the guide, it has been REALLY confusing understanding the decorators, especially since im new in ZF. Now i can change the default. :-) I will give it a go in next week.